# Is it possible to have multiple wordpress admin URL?

Tags: wordpress, url, authentication

Is it possible to have more than one admin url?

For example,

```
example.com/wp-admin,
example.com/admin
example.com/admin-login
```

etc.

Comment: you can just make a redirect - point the new ones to the original one

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe redirect the URLS to the admin page with something like this on Apache. In the rewrite rule 'foo' is the URL the user provided and 'bar' is where to redirect them.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/foo\.html$"  "/bar.html" [PT]
```